# Read Value from Textarea in HTML and Display formatted text in Popup

Tags: javascript, css, popup

Below is the code where I want to read the value from Textarea and display it in popup.

For example, an Address which is formatted text, the above code works but the text which is read is unformatted, I want it to be formatted.

Please help as I am looking alternative to bootstrap modal.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>
      Popup Demo
    </title>
  </head>
<body>
<script>
    var previewOpen;
    function preview() {
        previewOpen = window.open("", "previewOpen", "width=500, height=600, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes");
        previewOpen.document.body.innerHTML = document.getElementById("AFlogs").value; // Get the value of text area and run HTML code
    }
</script>

<div class="bg-modal">LOGS:
<img src="Zoom.png" onclick="preview()" style="float: right;" width="25" height="25" id="preview"/> 
<textarea class="form-control taAfLogs" id="AFlogs"></textarea>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Formated how???

Comment: Did you try wrapping everything with ta `<pre>` tag like `previewOpen.document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + document.getElementById("AFlogs").value +  '</pre>'`

Comment: Ibex, It worked like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: Ibex, once I open the preview and close it, it does not open again, any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

eh sorry couldnt get popup to work so doin a href but sure its easy to fix after ya see some of it someone will fix it

```js
 $('#click').click(function() {
  var html = document.getElementById("text").value;
var dataURI = 'data:text/html,' + encodeURIComponent(html);
window.location.href = (dataURI);
console.log(dataURI);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id = 'text'></textarea>
<button id = 'click' onclick=''>open popup</button>
```